# Object is possibly 'undefined' on nested object property despite typechecking

Tags: typescript

I have a nested object and a function which takes two parameters , which are used to dynamically select the value of an inner property.

I type check the first property, but when I try to check the inner property there is an error on the first property: `"Object is possibly 'undefined'."` , although I just checked it.

Here is the code:

```
type InnerProp = {
  ok?: string
}

type keyName = 'thing' | 'other';

type IResultTypeData = {
  [key in keyName]?: InnerProp;
};

const myObj: IResultTypeData = {
  thing: {
    ok: 'g'
  },
  other: {
    ok: 'g'
  }
}

function test(objKey: keyof typeof myObj, objInnerKey: keyof InnerProp) {

  if (objKey in myObj && myObj[objKey] && objInnerKey in myObj[objKey]) {

    return myObj[objKey][objInnerKey];
  }
}
```

The error is on `objInnerKey in myObj[objKey]`.

I can get around this by creating a variable for myObj[objKey], and the error then disappears:

```
function test(objKey: keyof typeof myObj, objInnerKey: keyof InnerProp) {

  if (objKey in myObj && myObj[objKey]) {

    const myObjProp = myObj[objKey];

    if (myObjProp && objInnerKey in myObjProp) {     // <-- works

      return myObjProp[objInnerKey];
      }
  }
}
```

But that requires me to create an extra nested if statement and an extra variable each time I need to reference a nested property.
So why doesn't typescript accept this type check: `&& myObj[objKey] && objInnerKey in myObj[objKey]` ?

Here is an [example](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.1.6&fileType=.tsx&code=LAKALgngDgpgBASQHZJgJwApoPZTgXjgG9Q45sBrAfgC44BnMNASyQHNQBfUUSWOCjAgA5AIYBbeIQDkYABas20uAB8407PPTSA3D3DR4CAEox6AVwA2YACqGAIqLCiCxUnADagiHFYChYpIAurSIKOhYuHognNEAxthIjHDiEADyAEYAVnQmZla2Dk4uhCQgZPKKdGVkZJR00krunAA07ppy6NXudRQNTeVw3DH6AGbmSHFgzIlwYGZgABTY2QDSQnTe2KNzhtsp6dkt5NnIqGjrEJtC%2B2cROFAAlG6DAPSvvjvLa0K%2BSAeZLJwABkwIB2Q8KyylyCzxqcHetQSSTA4KykTwhFSgMhPwgQWi7kRZGYX2x2QxILBULuF1%2BfnJ6IecKJH1qcDQMDA5jQ-0ZGNxWVpMOiZGJtWGYo%2Bks%2BcG%2B0PpfMOQNBaMFMKpJyF4TpPgZyvVQlhL3ZnO5vLVUJhguFRtFQy4QA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGYBfEWg&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA&tokens=false)

Comment: See [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) and the answer(s) to the linked question(s)